# Exact green color of example in Beamer

Tags: beamer, color

I'd would like to use the same green colour as in the example mode.
Does it coincide with `\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}`?

Is it possible to use it without defining a new color?
(Maybe using something like `\structure` or `\alert`).

I'm simply starting with

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}.
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear: which example mode in Beamer? which green color? Would you have a link?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to set your color:

```
\setbeamercolor{block title}
{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg} 

\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{use=alerted
text,fg=alerted text.fg,bg=alerted  text.fg!20!bg} 

\setbeamercolor{block title example}
{use=example text,fg=example text.fg,bg=example 
text.fg!20!bg}
 
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,
use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg}  

\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}
{parent=normal text,use=block title alerted,bg=block 
title alerted.bg!50!bg}

\setbeamercolor{block body example}
{parent=normal text,use=block title example,
bg=block title example.bg!50!bg}
```